# Redirect output from cmd.exe executed remotely with PsExec

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, psexec, system.diagnostics

I have searched high and low, read countless pages and questions regarding similar subjects to this but have yet to find a question that asks exactly this or works for my situation:

I have a C# program that is using a System.Diagnostics.Process and utilizes the RedirectStandardOutput and BeginOutputReadLine methods as well as the OutputDataReceived event to re-route the output from my process into a textbox. The command being executed is as follows:

`./PsExec.exe \\MACHINENAME -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD cmd /c \\RemotePath\BatchFile.bat arg1 arg2 arg3`

When I run this in a cmd window on my local machine, it outputs all of the text and info from my batch file, but for whatever reason when I redirect it through the Process in my C# code, the only thing that is outputted to my textbox is:

```
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Connecting to MACHINENAME...

Starting PSEXESVC service on MACHINENAME...

Connecting with PsExec service on MACHINENAME...

Starting cmd on MACHINENAME...

cmd exited on MACHINENAME with error code 0.
```

My question is, it there a way to get the entire output of the remote cmd to redirect in my program? (i.e. if i replace "\RemotePath\BatchFile.bat" with "ipconfig" so that the ipconfig is getting run on the remote computer, could i get that ipconfig info to redirect into the textbox in my program).

**EDIT: Added code here**

```
string cmd = @"./PsExec.exe \\MACHINENAME -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD cmd /c \\RemotePath\" + batchToExecute + " " + args;

var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; //False for testing
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = ("/c " + cmd);

process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (batchToExecute.Equals(batchName1)) { output1 += (e.Data + "\n"); }
    else if (batchToExecute.Equals(batchName2)) { output2 += (e.Data + "\n"); }
    else if (batchToExecute.Equals(batchName3)) { output3 += (e.Data + "\n"); }
};

process.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (batchToExecute.Equals(batchName1)) { output1 += (e.Data + "\n"); }
    else if (batchToExecute.Equals(batchName2)) { output2 += (e.Data + "\n"); }
    else if (batchToExecute.Equals(batchName2)) { output3 += (e.Data + "\n"); }
};
process.Start();

process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

process.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: {0}", process.ExitCode);
int processReturn = process.ExitCode;

process.Close();
```

Comment: For whatever reason, you're only receiving the text written to standard error, not the text written to standard output.  If you can't work out why, you'll need to post the actual code.

Comment: Hopefully a .NET expert will sweep in here and explain the problem.  But failing that, as a troubleshooting step, what happens if you don't redirect standard error?  (That is, set `.RedirectStandardError` to `false` and don't call the `.BeginErrorReadLine` function.)

Comment: ... also, where does `e2` come from?  It looks like it should just be `e` ?

Comment: If I do not redirect the output, all the correct ipconfig info is displayed in the cmd window that pops up, and then the cmd window closes. The e2 is because this was at one point inside of a method that used a variable e and I never went back and changed it. And yes, I can only hope that some .NET wizard comes and tells me that I'm doing something stupid and there is an easy fix...

Comment: The code as posted looks to me like it shouldn't work at all, because it uses a variable `e2` that as far as I can see is never defined.  You've also defined a variable `e` that is never used.  Please clarify.

Comment: What happens if you *do* redirect the standard output stream but *don't* redirect the standard error stream?

Comment: The e2/e are only different because when I pasted this in, I cleaned it up a little to make it readable. I changed the e2 to an e because I realized the e2 wasnt necessary anymore, but I guess I forgot to change them all. Ill fix it now, but thats not the issue I assure you. When I redirect standard output but not standard error I get mixed results. If I am running my batch file, I get nothing. When I run ipconfig, I get the first line of output and then nothing after that.

Comment: OK.  For future reference, please don't post code in a question that you haven't tested.  By all means clean it up, but verify that the cleaned-up version both runs and still exhibits the problem - you'd be amazed at how often a seemingly irrelevant change makes the problem go away, or otherwise makes it harder for people to spot. :-)

Comment: What class is `output1` ?

Comment: Output1,2 and 3 are strings in the same class as this code that are supposed to hold the output of the Psexec Process. Those strings are then being displayed in a textbox to show the user what happened with their batch file/command.